# DirectX Toolkit loaded model with custom HLSL shader Vertex shader input signature

Tags: c++, input, hlsl, vertex-shader, direct3d11

I am working on a project in which I use DirectX Toolkit to load FBX models. As I understood, DXTK does not support HLSL shaders for its models, so I have to get the model information (vertex buffer, index buffer, etc.) from the model object and implement a standart Direct3D drawing, if I want to use HLSL shaders for the rendering.

My problem is, that I can't reach the texture coordinates from the vertex shader. For testing, I set the vertex shader to pass through the coordinates to the pixel shader, where I color the whole object with the texture coordinates like this:

```
float4(input.texCoord, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

In the result, the whole object is black, so the texcoords are (0.0, 0.0) everywhere. I checked the model with the DXTK Model::Draw(...) funcion, and it is textured the correct way, so my model, and my model loading code seems correct.

I learnt that DXTK model loading uses the following vertex buffer declaration:

```
const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC VertexPositionNormalTangentColorTexture::InputElements[] =
{
    { "SV_Position", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "NORMAL",      0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TANGENT",     0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR",       0, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,     0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD",    0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,       0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
```

So I tried to match my vertex shader input structure like this:

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float3 pos : SV_Position;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float4 tangent : TANGENT;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD;
};
```

Here is how I load the model:

```
void SceneObject::LoadMesh(
    std::shared_ptr<DX::DeviceResources> deviceResources,
    const wchar_t* modelFile)
{
    auto device = deviceResources->GetD3DDevice();
    EffectFactory fx(device);
    this->model = Model::CreateFromCMO(device, modelFile, fx, true);
}
```

And here is my draw function:

```
void SceneObject::Draw(std::shared_ptr<DX::DeviceResources> deviceResources)
{
    auto device = deviceResources->GetD3DDevice();
    auto context = deviceResources->GetD3DDeviceContext();
    CommonStates states(device);

    context->UpdateSubresource(
        this->vsConstantBuffer.Get(),
        0,
        NULL,
        &this->vsConstantBufferData,
        0,
        0);

    context->UpdateSubresource(
        this->psConstantBuffer.Get(),
        0,
        NULL,
        &this->psConstantBufferData,
        0,
        0);

    //model->Draw(context, states, local, view, proj);
    XMVECTOR qid = XMQuaternionIdentity();
    const XMVECTORF32 scale = { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f };
    const XMVECTORF32 translate = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };
    //XMVECTOR rotate = XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYaw(0, XM_PI / 2.f, -XM_PI / 2.f);
    XMVECTOR rotate = XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYaw(0, 0, 0);
    XMMATRIX worldMatrix = XMLoadFloat4x4(&this->vsConstantBufferData.model);
    XMMATRIX local = XMMatrixMultiply(worldMatrix, XMMatrixTransformation(g_XMZero, qid, scale, g_XMZero, rotate, translate));
    //this->model->Draw(context, states, local, XMLoadFloat4x4(&vsConstantBufferData.view), XMLoadFloat4x4(&vsConstantBufferData.projection), false);

    XMStoreFloat4x4(&this->vsConstantBufferData.model, local);

    for each(auto& mesh in model->meshes)
    {
        for each (auto& part in mesh->meshParts)
        {
            context->IASetVertexBuffers(
                0,
                1,
                part->vertexBuffer.GetAddressOf(),
                &part->vertexStride,
                &part->vertexOffset
                );

            context->IASetIndexBuffer(
                part->indexBuffer.Get(),
                part->indexFormat,
                0
                );

            context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(part->primitiveType);

            //context->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout.Get());
            context->IASetInputLayout(part->inputLayout.Get());

            // Attach our vertex shader.
            context->VSSetShader(
                vertexShader.Get(),
                nullptr,
                0
                );

            // Send the constant buffer to the graphics device.
            context->VSSetConstantBuffers(
                0,
                1,
                vsConstantBuffer.GetAddressOf()
                );

            // Attach our pixel shader.
            context->PSSetShader(
                pixelShader.Get(),
                nullptr,
                0
                );

            // Send the constant buffer to the graphics device.
            context->PSSetConstantBuffers(
                1,
                1,
                psConstantBuffer.GetAddressOf()
                );

            context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, diffuseTexture.GetAddressOf());
            context->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, linearSampler.GetAddressOf());

            // Draw the objects.
            context->DrawIndexed(
                part->indexCount,
                part->startIndex,
                0
                );
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more code, you can check my whole project here: https://github.com/GiGu92/WaterRenderingDemo

What am I messing up?

Comment: I managed to get around the problem temporarily, as I implemented procedurally generated plane mesh, but you can still browse my project at the github link above. See the commit "minor changes (texcoords still not working)", that is where I am still trying to draw a loaded model with my shader.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above doesn't indicate where you are creating your vertex shader.

For CMOs, take a look at `Src\Shaders\DGSLEffect.fx` for how they are used with custom shaders.

The default `EffectFactory` or `DGSLEffectFactory` is setting up a standard vertex & pixel shader for rendering the `Model` as a `BasicEffect`, `SkinnedEffect`, or `DGSLEffect`. Details on doing custom rendering are covered in the [wiki](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Model), but I suggest your first get it rendering using the default effects as you expect it.  See the [tutorial](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rendering%20a%20model).

You can override the entire pipeline if desired in a number of ways:

- Implement your own IEffect* interfaces and IEffectFactory to use with the Model loader
- Override the shaders while rendering directly with [ModelMesh](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ModelMesh) / [ModelMeshParts](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ModelMeshPart)

For CMO files, the vertex format is indeed either `VertexPositionNormalTangentColorTexture` or `VertexPositionNormalTangentColorTextureSkinning`, although for SDKMESH files it is a bit more variable.

As always, ensure you have the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) enabled and check the HRESULT of any Direct3D function that returns one to ensure you aren't missing some configuration or API usage problem.